# Update the data of the table without using refreshing function based on input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, json

Goal:
When you write any letter or number in the id="searches" you should display new data in the table without refreshing the website. The effect of using the "refresh" or similiar effect is to use F5 function.
You update and not refreshing the table.

When you empthy the input text box (id="searches" ), the default data should display.

Default data is:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Problem:
I do not now how to do it in order to update new data in the table?

Info:
*I'm using asp.nget mvc
*I have used jSon before but I do not know if it relevant to use it in this context. Maybe using angular or similiar?
*The definition of update is to retrieve new information from the database and filtrating the current data in the table.

Thank you!

```html
<input type="text" name="search" id="searches"><br>

<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>a</th>
 <th>b</th>
 <th>c</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>3</td>
 <td>4</td>
 <td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this

```
$('#searches').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url:"your serverpage.asp",
    method:"GET"    
    }).done(function(jsonData){
        //do necessary functions to update table contents using the obtained jsonData
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about jSon, but yes if this is the question you can do it in angular. This is for version 1, but almost the same way you can do it for angular2. Note that 2 is in still beta.

UPDATE: sorry, misread the question and this is not adding item, but filtering. But for the simple show case I believe is enough.

Angular1 solution:

your js file:

```
 var _text = '';

  $scope.search = {
    text: function(newValue) {
      if (arguments.length) {
        alert('Calling server for new data')
      }
      return arguments.length ? (_text = newValue) : _text;
    }
  };

  $scope.rows = [
    { col1: 'a', col2: 'b', col3: 'c' },
    { col1: '4', col2: '5', col3: '6' },
    { col1: '9', col2: '6', col3: '4' }
  ]
```

your html:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in rows | filter: search.text()">
    <th>{{ row.col1 }}</th>
    <th>{{ row.col2 }}</th>
    <th>{{ row.col3 }}</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/F5oU3uTLikm3Kz53iMMQ?p=preview

UPDATE 2:

if I understood correctly you are missing the retrieval from the backend... I can show you the basic, but after it really depends on your needs, as authentication, etc

To achieve it you can add event to your search box and call the server for new data. I updated the plunker to be able to call the server after changing the input.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I need to add some complementory in the criteria based on your feedback.